# Where should I put methods to be used by multiple controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have an admin controller and view to manage admin tasks. Many of those tasks are very similar to tasks conducted in my two main model-backed controllers, Users and Materials. I'm trying to dry up my code so I want to put it somewhere, but where?

For example:

As an admin I can delete a Material from my admin view but so can a User from their material view. I have almost identical code for this in both the admin and material controllers with the only exception that the redirect goes to a different place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails4 way is to use [Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), even though there is [some discussion](https://gist.github.com/ryanb/4172391) going on about it. Still, I like this approach, even though [most of the material you find](https://www.google.at/search?q=rails%20controller%20concerns&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3ade-DE%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=Si8_UvPwIIbItAbm5YHIAg) will be more about models than about controllers.

### A simple example

If you are on Rails 3 (as your tag implies), just add a `concerns`-folder into your `controllers`-folder and add it to your autoload-path:

```
#config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns)
```

For instance, I have something like this in `app/controllers/concerns/can_can_sanitizer.rb`

```
module CanCanSanitizer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter do
      resource = controller_path.singularize.gsub('/', '_').to_sym
      method = "#{resource}_params" 
      params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
    end
  end
end
```

I include this into my application_controller just like any other module:

```
include CanCanSanitizer
```

Admittedly, not the best use-case, but it should give you a headstart.

Answer (score 1):

If the AdminsController is inherited from UsersController, you can put such methods in UsersController, judging the difference from method arguments or controller name or code before `super`.

If Admin and User has no inheritance, you can create a separate module and get both Admin and User to include it.